# How can one mark a flag as required with gflags?

Tags: python, gflags

I use gflags like this:

```
flags.DEFINE_string('logdir', None,
                    'Directory where logs are stored.')
```

However, I would like gflags to show the help when somebody does not define `--logdir`. How can I make this flag required?

([This](https://github.com/gflags/python-gflags/blob/master/tests/gflags_validators_test.py#L189) looks a bit as if it should be possible, but I couldn't find any documentation about how to use gflags with Python.)

Answer (score 6):

Your code should look something like this.  The MarkFlagAsRequired must come before FLAGS(argv) call.

```
def main(argv):
    gflags.MarkFlagAsRequired('logdir')      
    argv = gflags.FLAGS(argv)
```

Comment: UPDATE: `MarkFlagAsRequired` is now `mark_flag_as_required`