# How to make flags as necessary in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using [`tf.app.flags`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/app/flags) to parse command line arguments in my code. Is there any way I can make some flags as necessary (as in `argparse`)? Using default value as `None` doesn't seem to help

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305560/how-can-one-mark-a-flag-as-required-with-gflags since tf's flags resemble gflags?

Comment: Thanks, apparently, tf's flags is actually abseil flags (formerly gflags), they just import it internally :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @etarion 's comment, it seems the correct method to use is `flags.mark_flag_as_required`. Note that this won't work if the default value is not `None`.